# Create A Directory Before Several Gradle Tasks

Tags: gradle

I have several tasks that require a sub-directory of `build` to exist.

What is the best way to achieve this?

So far I have this:

```
afterEvaluate {
    mkdir "$buildDir/work"
}
```

And this:

```
task prepareDirs {
    mkdir "$buildDir/test"
}
```

The second one works because it is run in the configuration phase and so I don't need to put dependsOn on all the tasks that require it.

- Are there other options?
- Is `mkdir` even the right way to do it?
- At what point is the `buildDir` created? Can I extend that task?

EDIT: I noticed that both of these fail if I chain the clean task on the command line before  my main tasks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should work. Note that `prepareDirs` must have constraint `mustRunAfter clean`, to solve the issue you mentioned in your EDIT

```
// task responsible to create the tmp/work dir
task prepareDirs {
    mustRunAfter clean
    doLast {
        mkdir "$buildDir/work"
    }
}

// make all tasks depend on the prepareDirs task
// exept 'clean' and 'prepareDirs' (avoid circular dependency)
tasks.each {
    if (it != prepareDirs && it != clean) {
        it.dependsOn prepareDirs
    }
}
```

If you don't have much tasks that require the `build/work` dir and don't want to make all tasks depend on you `prepareDirs` task, you can do that :

```
[myTask1, myTask2, myTask3].each {
    it.dependsOn prepareDirs
}
```